# SQL Statement loads very slow with Order By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql statement below and returns in 0.149seconds:

```
SELECT Trans.Transid, TransDetail.TransDetailID FROM Trans  
LEFT JOIN TransDetail ON Trans.Reference = TransDetail.TransID 
LIMIT 1000
```

I modified by adding Order By and it grealy slows down the return to 1min 20 seconds

```
SELECT Trans.Transid, TransDetail.TransDetailID FROM Trans  
LEFT JOIN TransDetail ON Trans.Reference = TransDetail.TransID 
ORDER BY Trans.Transid, TransDetail.TransDetailID 
LIMIT 1000
```

These are so far what I done but still didn't improve the speed:

1.) Added Index for Trans.TransID, Trans.Reference, and TransDetail.TransDetailID

2.) Tried putting the Limit to even 1 but still returns very slow

3.) Tried doing ORDER BY Trans.Transid and it returns in 0.223 seconds

4.) Tried doing ORDER BY TransDetail.TransDetailID and it returns in 48.365 seconds

Doing the TransDetail.TrasnsDetailID only in Order by is slower compared than having the Trans.TransID. But doing both makes it very very slow.

What's the best way to do order by to make it faster?

Comment: Try inner join in place of left join. Sometime inner join is faster than left ,right join.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: May I know how to extract the Create Table code from creating the table? I created the table using the import utility of MS Access to MySQL.

Comment: I did try Inner Join but didn't help. It's still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use 2 limits.
First on the smallest & fastest table.
Then on the result of the left join.

```
SELECT tr.Transid, det.TransDetailID 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Transid, Reference
    FROM Trans
    ORDER BY Transid
    LIMIT 1000
 ) tr
LEFT JOIN TransDetail det ON det.TransID = tr.Reference
ORDER BY tr.Transid, det.TransDetailID 
LIMIT 1000
```

It would benefit from an index on Trans.TransID for the sub-query.
But I assume that TransID is the primary key on that table anyway.

And it would also benefit from an index on TransDetail.TransID.
To speed up the join on TransDetail.

Small test [here](https://rextester.com/LQH11903)